# Hago map a un Array de un UseState, pero no me renderiza los elementos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

obtengo un array de objetos desde mi base SQL mediante un fetch, obtengo correctamente el arreglo y lo seteo a mi State. Sin embargo, en otro componente (al que paso el valor del State con props) que es el encargado de renderizar los elementos de los objetos en una tabla, estos no se ven renderizados cuando el State se actualiza.

Mis pasos serían estos:
Hago un fetch> seteo el valor al State> lo paso por props> aplico un map al state>No se renderizan las  con los datos obtenidos

Con un use Effect he verificado que los datos efectivamente si están llegando a mi componente, pero igual no renderiza. Dejo parte de mi código.

```
app.js

  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState("")

  async function getTableData() {
    await fetch('http://localhost:2000/API/usersList').
    then(response => response.json()).
    then(json => {
      console.log(json.response)
      setTableData(json.response)})
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTableData()
    
  }, [])
```

Y la parte del elemento que debe renderizar

```
return (
    <div>
    {data.length>0?
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Passport</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>Skills</th>
            <th>Actions:</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {data.map( (item) => {
            
            <tr>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td>{item.email}</td>
                <td>{item.passport}</td>
                <td>{item.city}</td>
                <td>{item.status}</td>
                <td>{item.level}</td>
                <td>{item.salary}</td>
                <td>{item.startDate}</td>
                <td>{item.skills}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src={edit} alt="edit" />
                    <img src={remove} alt="delete" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            
        })
        }
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
    :
    <h1>Wait...</h1>
    }
    </div>
  )
```

He intentado por ejemplo, renderizar en un

o  el nombre de alguna cuadricula de la tabla y si funciona por ejemplo usando data[0].name

Comment: Ya he encontrado la solución, no habia colocado un return luego de usar {} en la funcion flecha que me retorna las filas de la tablas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra de las cosas que acabo de notar es que en tu tbody estas haciendo un map, pero al usar un callback con llaves "{}" te haria falta el return

Ejemplo:

```html
<tbody>
        {data.map( (item) => {
            return (<tr>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.lastName}</td>
                <td>{item.email}</td>
                <td>{item.passport}</td>
                <td>{item.city}</td>
                <td>{item.status}</td>
                <td>{item.level}</td>
                <td>{item.salary}</td>
                <td>{item.startDate}</td>
                <td>{item.skills}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src={edit} alt="edit" />
                    <img src={remove} alt="delete" />
                </td>
            </tr>)
            
        })
        }
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al ser una llamada asíncrona, debes de poner un estado "cargando" o similar para saber cuando ha acabado la llamad a la api.

Esta guía me ayudó a entenderlo.

[Data Fetching con React Usando usestate y useEffect](https://www.escuelafrontend.com/data-fetching-con-react)

Comment: Hola, tengo entendido es igual al renderizado condicional que he aplicado yo usando operadores ternarios "?".Igual intenté como mencionas y tampoco me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías revisar paso a paso tu código

1.- Cuando creas un estado y sabes que datos manejarán, en este caso entiendo que es un arreglo, creo que su estado inicial debería ser un arreglo vacío

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])
```

2.- Revisar si en el componente está recibiendo esa propiedad, la forma más sencilla es con las Devtools de React, o la otra forma es hacer en el componente que recibe las props un simple return de las props, para ver si estas capturando el key correcto, capaz estas capturando un undefined y por eso nunca te lista

```
const Componente = (props) => {
  return props
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente habia usado las devs tool y lo que conforma mi props "data" está llegando, es un array de objetos, pero aún así no renderiza. Respecto al estado inicial, fue un error, lo habia modificado para intentar algo, pero con [] tampoco me funcionaba, ni funciona.